# Need to delete files (images) from webserver if corresponding record in table does not exist (php/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I upload a few thousand images a day to my webserver.

The image filenames are in the following format: photoXXXXXXX-Y.jpeg where XXXXXXX is the record id and Y is the number of images. (example - photo1357936-2.jpeg)

In a MySQL table there is a column containing the record id (sysid) and a column for Y (num_of_photos). There is a maximum of 12 images associated with an id.

The table is updated daily and records containing the id's are added or deleted.

I need to somehow iterate through the id's and compare against the record id portion of the image filename then the delete images that are no longer associated with a given id.

Or compare the record id portion of the image filename against the id's and delete the orphaned images. Whichever logic is more sound.

I can use a CRON to automate this task and know how to unset to delete the files, but not sure where to begin on the rest.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas?

You actually answered in your own question.

> I need to somehow iterate through the id's and compare against the record id portion of the image filename then the delete images that are no longer associated with a given id.

To give you some breadcrumbs though:

1) [`opendir`](http://www.php.net/opendir) & [`readdir`](http://www.php.net/readdir) to iterate files / folders to get filenames (perhaps recursively)

2) [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/preg_match) to get X and Y parts of the filename

3) [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/mysql_query) (with `mysql_connect` etc. before ofcourse) to get the record for X and Y.

4) [`mysql_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows) to see if there is an entry in the DB

5) if not: [`unlink`](http://www.php.net/unlink)

Comment: Great! I will try your suggestions. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// path to the images
$path_img='./media/images/inside/gallery';
// where images are listed in database
$table_name='gallery';
$field_name='file';
// unnecessary parts of filenames
$odd_tokens = array("_small", ".jpg", ".");

// limit number of image files to check, set to 10 for testing
$limit=10;
echo "begin\r\n";

//connection constants 
include './application/config/config.php';

try{
$pdo = new PDO( 'mysql:host='.config::$db_server.';dbname='.config::$db_name, config::$db_user, config::$db_pass );
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$r=$pdo->query('select count(1) cnt from '.$table_name)->fetch();
echo 'count images in database: '.$r['cnt']."\r\n";

// reset some counters
$cnt_files=0;
$cnt_checked=0;
$cnt_not_found=0;
$cnt_found=0;
$path=$path_img;
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
while ($cnt_files != $limit && false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $cnt_files++;
            if($entry > "") {
                    $cnt_checked++;
                    $img_name = str_replace ($odd_tokens,'',$path . '/' . $entry);

                    if(!checkExistsDb($pdo, $img_name, $table_name, $field_name)) {
                            $cnt_not_found++;
                            echo 'rm ' . $path . '/' . $entry . "\r\n";
//this will delete files                                unlink($path.'/'.$entry);
                    } else {
                            $cnt_found++;
                    }
            }
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
else echo 'not found: '.$path."\r\n";
unset($pdo); 
echo 'files: '.$cnt_files.' checked: '.$cnt_checked.' not_found: '.$cnt_not_found.' found: '.$cnt_found;

function checkExistsDb($pdo, $img_name, $table_name, $field_name) {

    try{
    $st = $pdo->prepare('SELECT ' . $field_name . ' FROM ' . $table_name . ' WHERE '. $field_name . '=:filename');
    $st->execute(array(':filename'=>$img_name));
    $result = $st->fetchAll();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $result?true:false;
}
```

Thanks for
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/290936-cleanup-imgp-folder-and-image-folder-questions/